# Loop through csv files in folder, add column one file at a time

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My code is able to loop through the folder but right now its hardcoded to do one csv. I was hoping to loop through all the csv in the folder and add the column to each one.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
test_miti_files = glob.glob('test_miti/*.csv', recursive=True)
all_test_miti_files = []


path = "C:/Users/j/Desktop/*.csv"
for file in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=["ID"]).set_axis(["ID"], axis=1)
    all_test_miti_files.append(df)
test_miti_files_result = pd.concat(all_test_miti_files, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
out = pd.merge(file, test_miti_files_result, left_on="ID", right_on="ID", how="left")
csv1 = pd.merge(file,test_miti_files_result[['ID']].assign(**{'test_miti_Flag': test_miti_files_result.ID}), on='ID', how='left')
csv1.to_csv(file + "test", sep=",", index=False, na_rep="N/A")
```

Updated my code to look like this

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
test_miti_files = glob.glob('test_miti/*.csv', recursive=True)
all_test_miti_files = []

path = "C:/Users/j/Desktop/*.csv"
for file in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=["ID"]).set_axis(["ID"], axis=1)
    all_test_miti_files.append(df)
    test_miti_files_result = pd.concat(all_test_miti_files, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    out = pd.merge(file, test_miti_files_result, left_on="ID", right_on="ID", how="left")
    csv1 = pd.merge(file,test_miti_files_result[['ID']].assign(**{'test_miti_Flag': test_miti_files_result.ID}), on='ID', how='left')
    df.to_csv(file + "_wider", sep=",", index=False, na_rep="N/A")
```

But now I get this error.

```
TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'str'> was passed
```

on the
`out = pd.merge`
line. Any suggestions

Comment: What is your question or problem here?

Comment: @ScottBoston Well right now its hardcoded to read one csv and add a column to that one but I was hoping to loop through the folder and add the column to every csv.

Comment: Are you sure? To me it seems your looping through the files one at a time...

Comment: @Bigga I don't think it adds the column to each file.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the files, but then merging all the CSV data into a single dataframe. Then, you are adding a column to that (outside the loop) and writing it once to a file, so now you have ONE CSV file with the data from ALL original files in the directory, with one extra column.

What you want is something along the lines of:

```
for file in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=["ID"]).set_axis(["ID"], axis=1)
    //code to add column to "df" goes here
    df.to_csv(file + "_wider", sep=",", index=False, na_rep="N/A")
```

This makes a new CSV with a different name (i.e. data1.csv with the extra column will be written to data1_wider.csv, data2.csv will be written to data2_wider.csv, etc.). If you want to overwrite the file you can just give the same filename.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I updated my code/question but I'm getting an error.

Comment: @e417927 What is the error?

Comment: its in the updated question but its `TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'str'> was passed`